# how to create an instance of class python

Tags: python, class

I am learning about classes in Python, using Python 3.4.1 and am attempting to make a class and then call the methods from that class.  I have looked at other questions related to this and unfortunately, I can't seem to make it work.  Here is my class (copied straight from the book)

```
class Counter(object):
    """Models a counter"""
    instances = 0
    def __init__(self):
        """Sets up counter"""
        Counter.instances += 1
        self.reset()
    def reset(self):
        """Sets counter to 0"""
        self._value=0
    def increment(self, amount = 1):
        """Adds amount to counter"""
        self._value += amount
    def decrement(self, amount = 1):
        """Subtracts amount from counter"""
        self._value -= amount
    def getValue(self):
        return self._value
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._value)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        """Returns True if self == other and False if not"""
        if self is other:
            return True
        if type(self)!=type(other):
            return False
        return self._value==other._value
```

and this is how I'm calling it from another file (in the same folder):

```
import Counter
h = Counter()
print(h.getValue())
```

and this is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python34/learning/classtest.py", line 3, in <module>
h = Counter()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I can type import Counter just fine into the shell, but when I get to h = Counter() I get the same error.  I know I'm doing something wrong, but what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You named your module `Counter` too; the class is contained *in* the module:

```
import Counter

h = Counter.Counter()
```

Alternatively, import the class from the module:

```
from Counter import Counter

h = Counter()
```

This is why the [Python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends you use all lower-case names for your modules. In Python, the module name does **not** have to match the class contained, and you are not limited to just one class in a module. A module can contain just functions or any other Python object too.

Had you named your module file `counter` (all lowercase) instead, it would perhaps have been more obvious that the module and contained class are two distinct concepts. :-)

Comment: 18 seconds... dang it :)

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, the line:

```
import Counter
```

only makes the module `Counter` available for use.  If you want to use one of the tools that it contains, such as the class `Counter`, you need to qualify it with the module name:

```
import Counter
h = Counter.Counter()
```

Or, you can import the tools you want directly:

```
from Counter import Counter
h = Counter()
```

Here is a reference on [importing in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-import_stmt).

---

Also, PEP 8, the official style guide for Python code, states that [module names should be lowercase](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names):

> Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be
>   used in the module name if it improves readability. Python packages
>   should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of
>   underscores is discouraged.

Therefore, it would be best if you renamed the `Counter` module to `counter`.

Answer (score 0):

You want `Counter.Counter` instead, because your file is named `Counter.py` as well.

If you don't call `h = Counter.Counter()`, you are basically trying to invoke the module as a function:

```
>>> import math
>>> math()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

You have two options.

1. Call `import Counter` and then call `h = Counter.Counter()`

```
import Counter
h = Counter.Counter()
print(h.getValue())
```

2. Call `from Counter import Counter` and then call `h = Counter()`

```
from Counter import Counter
h = Counter()
print(h.getValue())
```